# how to add the item, quantity, price and total to the listview

Tags: vb.net

please help me,

what if the customer buys many items. how to add the item, quantity, price and total to the listview. For example I press the "Pay" Button then the other item will show in the listview besides Milk
I have posted images here to understand me.

Thank you :)

[image]
**Check this image**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub list_column()

        With ListView1
            .View = View.Details
            .FullRowSelect = True
            .GridLines = True

            .Columns.Add("Customer")
            .Columns.Add("Item")
            .Columns.Add("Quantity")
            .Columns.Add("Price")
            .Columns.Add("Total")
            .Columns.Add("Amount Tendered")
            .Columns.Add("Amount Changed")

        End With

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Call list_column()

    End Sub

 Private Sub btn_Pay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Pay.Click

        Dim Milk As Integer
        Dim Coffee As Integer
        Dim Sugar As Integer
        Dim Coke As Integer
        Dim Cotton As Integer

        ' Price of the product
        Milk = 10
        Coffee = 30
        Sugar = 20
        Coke = 3
        Cotton = 4

        Dim item As Integer
        item = ListView1.Items.Count
        Dim list As New ListViewItem(txt_CustomerName.Text)

        'Milk
        list.SubItems.Add("Milk")
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_Milk.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(Milk)
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_Total.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountTendered.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountChanged.Text)
        ListView1.Items.Add(list)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could you explain better what the problem is? It's not clear what you need...

Comment: Honestly, do some reading and research into data tables, data binding and data grid views.  While you can 100% achieve this type of thing adding items to list views as you’re currently doing, long term you will get a simpler, more maintainable solution

Answer (score 0):

As Hursey said the way you are implementing this CRUD is not the ideal one, you could find amazing resources on how to implement this kind of projets on the internet and they will use most of the times DataGridViews.
To answer your question and for you to see how tedius it would be to implemented.
With the information that you have provided, to add a new list to your listview you would have to check each textbox to see if the have data written and then do the adding

```
    'Checking the milk
    If txt_Milk.Text <> "0" Then
        Dim list As New ListViewItem(txt_CustomerName.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add("Milk")
        List.SubItems.Add(txt_Milk.Text)
        List.SubItems.Add(Milk)
        List.SubItems.Add(txt_Total.Text)
        List.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountTendered.Text)
        List.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountChanged.Text)
        ListView1.Items.Add(List)
    End If

    'Checking the coffee
    If txt_Coffee.Text <> "0" Then
        Dim list As New ListViewItem(txt_CustomerName.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add("Coffee")
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_Coffee.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(Coffee")
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_Total.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountTendered.Text)
        list.SubItems.Add(txt_AmountChanged.Text)
        ListView1.Items.Add(list)
    End If

    'Continue with each item.....
```

As you see, it would be kinda of bruteforce code, it is not how it should be done.